# Update Server for extension type="file"

Tags: joomla-3.x, extension-update, manifest

I've developed a "file" extension that works just fine, but trying to publish it in JED I need to setup the update server entry, but I really don't know how to setup that for my new extension, which is of type "file".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="file" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
...
...
```

I have setup a lot of update servers for my other extensions which are plugins, but never setup for "files". So far my update server manifest look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updates>
   <update>
      <name>My Extension Name</name>
      <description>Description by me</description>
       <element>Don't know if this is needed</element>
      <type>file</type>
      <folder>Whats should I put in here?</folder>
      <client>0</client>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <infourl title="URL Info">http://something.com</infourl>
      <tags>
         <tag>stable</tag>
      </tags>
      <maintainer>MGS Creativa</maintainer>
      <maintainerurl>http://www.mgscreativa.com</maintainerurl>
      <section>Updates</section>
      <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[0123456789]"/>
   </update>
</updates>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sorry to ask, but finally got it working like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>Extension Name</name>
        <description>Extensin description</description>
        <element>String written in the "element" field of the #__extensions table for this extension entry</element>
        <type>file</type>
        <folder></folder>
        <client>0</client>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <infourl title="Link title">https://www.url.com-</infourl>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>MGS Creativa</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.mgscreativa.com</maintainerurl>
        <section>Updates</section>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[0123456789]"/>
    </update>
</updates>
```

Comment: Please could you mark the answer as "accepted" so others know it has been solved? Thanks

Comment: Ok, already done